# Does a real sequence $(X_n)$ with all terms between $0$ and $1/n$ have to eventually be decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Take a real sequence $(X_n)$ such that for any $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, $0$≤$x_n$≤$1/n$. At some point, does every term in the sequence have to be less than or equal to the prior one?  I think that it does but am unsure of how to prove it.

Comment: No. In fact, a sequence could increase to $\frac{1}{n}$, like $a_k = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+k}$. This is in fact an increasing sequence.

Comment: @ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг Ah, right. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

No, take for example:
$$x_n = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{|\sin(n)|}{2n} = \frac{2 - |\sin(n)|}{n}.$$